# Month to year Aggregation in plsql

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, aggregation

I have a fact table where I have each kpi name, value for the kpi and the month it belongs to. I need to do the aggregation from the month level to year level. For rolling up from month to year, I will use the confirmed dimension table (time dimension) to get to know the year for each month.

The challenge which I am facing is, I should not always do sum(kpi value) when I roll up from month to year. It will be avg, min or max depends on the kpi type. This I will get to know kpi dimension table where it has kpi name and kpi aggregation type.

I would require a help how I can  do this rolling up for all kpi with respect to its aggregation type.

Comment: You'd likely need to use dynamic SQL if you want the type of aggregation to be dynamic (and I'd be really cautious about applying `avg` to a set of aggregate values-- that is rarely mathematically correct).  Architecturally, I wouldn't expect that you'd be able to define new KPI's without writing code and I wouldn't expect that you'd regularly want to change one KPI from rolling up as an `avg` to a `min` so this isn't the sort of thing that it would makes sense to me to store in a table.

Comment: We have list of kpi in a dimension table for which the user will provide the values for each month to the fact table

Comment: @JustinCave - I assume the "proof of concept" I posted answers the doubt about needing dynamic SQL. Right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @mathguy - Probably.  I was reading the question differently but I'm guessing your interpretation was correct.  I'm still not sold on the usefulness of trying to dynamically specify the aggregate function or on the mathematical propriety of averaging monthly KPIs to annual values but you may not need dynamic SQL.

Comment: @JustinCave - I am in full agreement with all your points.  {:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what a KPI is; here is a "proof of concept" of how this may work.

```
with
     dim ( kpi, agg_type ) as (
       select 1, 'max' from dual union all
       select 2, 'avg' from dual
     ),
     facts ( kpi, val ) as (
       select 1,  100 from dual union all
       select 1,  300 from dual union all
       select 2,   14 from dual union all
       select 2, null from dual union all
       select 2,   20 from dual union all
       select 3,  500 from dual
     )
select f.kpi, 
       case max(d.agg_type) when 'max' then max(f.val)
                            when 'avg' then avg(f.val)
                            else            null      end as agg_val
from dim d right outer join facts f on d.kpi = f.kpi
group by f.kpi
;

       KPI    AGG_VAL
---------- ----------
         1        300
         2         17 
         3
```

(`avg_val` is null in the last row, and it would also be null if the `agg_type` in the `dim` table wasn't among those hard-coded in the query; happily, there is a finite number of well-defined aggregate functions, so the latter can be avoided.)